# Error count for two different patterns in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have made 2 forms of data patterns and wants to compare them in the form of error count.....when the 2 patterns are not equal, the error count should be high....i made the code including test bench, but when i ran behavioral sumilation, the error count is only high at value 0 and not at value 1.....I expect it to be high at both 0 and 1....please help me out in this, since I am new with verilog

here is the code

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module pattern(
clk,
 start,
 rst,enter code here
 clear,
 data_in1,
 data_in2,
 error
);

input [1:0] data_in1;
input [1:0] data_in2;

input clk;
input start;
input rst;
input clear;

output [1:0] error;
reg [1:0] comp_out;
reg [1:0] i = 0;

assign error = comp_out;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
comp_out = 0;
if(rst)
  comp_out = 0;
  else
    begin
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1)
        begin    
            if(data_in1[i] != data_in2[i])
                comp_out <= comp_out + 1;  
        end
    end  
end 

endmodule

here is the test bench for the above code
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_pattern();
// inputs
reg clk;
reg rst;
reg [1:0] data_in1;
reg [1:0] data_in2;
wire [1:0] error;
//outputs
//wire [15:0] count;

//instantiate the unit under test (UUT)
pattern uut (
  //  .count(count),
    .clk(clk),
    .start(start),
    .rst(rst),
    .clear(clear),
    .data_in1(data_in1),
    .data_in2(data_in2),
    .error(error)

);
initial begin
        clk = 1'b0;
        rst = 1'b1;
        repeat(4) #10 clk = ~clk;
        rst = 1'b0;
        forever #10 clk = ~clk; // generate a clock
    end
initial begin
    //initialize inputs
    clk = 0;
    //rst = 1;
    data_in1 = 2'b00;
    data_in2 = 2'b01;
    #100
    data_in1 = 2'b11;
    data_in2 = 2'b00;
    #100
    $finish;
    end
    //force rest after delay
    //#20 rst = 0;
    //#25 rst = 1;


endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When incrementing in a for loop you need to use blocking assignment (`=`), however when assigning flops you should use non-blocking assignment (`<=`). When you need to use a for loop to assign a flop, it is best to split the combinational and synchronous functionality into separate always blocks.

```
...
reg [1:0] comp_out, next_comb_out;

always @* begin : comb
  next_comp_out = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1) begin
    if (data_in1[i] != data_in2[i]) begin
      next_comp_out = next_comp_out + 1;
    end
  end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin : dff
  if (rst) begin
    comb_out <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    comb_out <= next_comp_out;
  end
end
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
begin
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i = i + 1)
    begin    
        if(data_in1[i] != data_in2[i])
            comp_out <= comp_out + 1;  
    end
end
```

This for loop doesn't work the way you think it does. Because this is a non-blocking assignment, only the last iteration of the loop actually applies. So only the last bit is actually being compared here.

If both bits of your data mismatch, then the loop unrolls to something which looks like this:

```
comp_out <= comp_out + 1;
comp_out <= comp_out + 1;
```

Because this is non-blocking, the RHS of the equation are both evaluated at the same time, leaving you with:

```
comp_out <= 0 + 1;
comp_out <= 0 + 1;
```

So even though you tried to use this as a counter, only the last line takes effect, and you get a mismatch count of '1', no matter how many bits mismatch.

Try using a blocking statement (`=`) for comp_out assignment instead.